# Where are missions found? Do you have to have a certain amount of levels until you can do missions?

Tags: tiny-tower

I have the app Tiny Tower on my iPad Air 2 and I've looked everywhere for the missions. In my research trying to find out why that is, I have found that I'm missing the stats section in the menu too. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Missions pop up as a button in top left with a person and exclamation mark.

> Missions are tasks you can complete to earn Bux (or sometimes coins) in Tiny Tower. After the 5-year-anniversary update, missions appear randomly. When a mission is available, a blue square with an exclamation mark appears in the upper left of the screen.

*from Tiny Tower wikia*

Comment: This does answers where the missions are to be found